# Elasticsearch Filters

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I will receive the filter inputs from the front-end via node js some may be null or empty but in the elasticsearch query filter all the field should be present . How to get response even the inputs are empty for some filters ?

```
 elasticClient.search({
                 index: 'pubmed-index',
                 type: 'pubmed-paper',
                 body: {
                  query: {
                      bool: {
                          must: {
                              match: {
                                  Abstract: `${searchKeyword}`
                              }
                          },
                          filter:
                          {"or":[{
                                  term: 
                                  {
                                  "Publication Type": `${searchPublicationType}`
                                  }},
                              {

                              "range": {
                                "Date Completed": {
                                    "gte" :`${searchGreaterYear}||/y`,
                                    "lte" : `${searchLesserYear}||/y`,
                                    "format" :"yyyy"
                                }
                            }
                          }
                           ]}



                      }
                  }
              }
               }).then(function (resp) {
                   console.log(resp.hits.hits);
                   return res.json(resp.hits.hits)
               }, function (err) {
                   console.log(err.message);
                   return res.json(err.message)
               });
```

I need the output either for publication type or date completed if any of the fields are missing

Comment: Can you share the query generated by your code.

Comment: `
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "match": {"Abstract": "cancer" } },
            "filter": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "Publication Type": "Review"
                    }
                },
                {
  "range": {
                        "Date Completed": {
                            "gte": "1800",
                            "lte": "2017",
                            "format": "yyyy"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        `

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you take a look on the [search template](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.5/search-template.html) functionality provided by Elasticsearch.

It uses [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/) as a template language and allows to have for example conditional clauses:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "match": {
          "line": "{{text}}" 
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        {{#line_no}} 
          "range": {
            "line_no": {
              {{#start}} 
                "gte": "{{start}}" 
                {{#end}},{{/end}} 
              {{/start}} 
              {{#end}} 
                "lte": "{{end}}" 
              {{/end}} 
            }
          }
        {{/line_no}} 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and few more options.

I was using it on production for a similar case - to omit some filters when a user does not put any value for them.